# SqlConnection hangs on open

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sqlconnection

I've got a program that send's multiple request in parallel to a SQL Server instance. Of all my concurrent requests, one of them always block for a few seconds on db.open().

```
void MyMethod()
{
    var brands = new  List<string>{"Chevy", "Honda", "Ford", "GM"};
    var foundCars = new  ConcurrentBag<Car>();   

    Parallel.ForEach(brands, brand =>
    {
      logger.Trace(brand + " before enqueue");
      foundsCars.Enqueue(FindCar(brand));
      logger.Trace(brand + " after enqueue");
    });
}

public Car FindCars(string brand)
{
   using (var db = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
   {
     sqlLogger.Trace("Brand " + " brand " + " before db open");
     db.Open();
     sqlLogger.Trace("Brand " + " brand " + " after db open");
     using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCmd, db))
     {
        while (reader.Read())
        {              
            //SQL SELECT Stuff going on
        }
     }
   }
}
```

If I'd look in my trace I'd see something like this, the order depends on the db response time I guess, in this scenario Honda is the data being slowly processed but it would not always be:

```
12:00:00.0000 Chevy before enqueue 
12:00:00.0000 Honda before enqueue 
12:00:00.0000 Ford before enqueue
12:00:00.0000 GM before enqueue
12:00:00.0200 Brand Chevy before db open
12:00:00.0300 Brand Honda before db open
12:00:00.0200 Brand Ford before db open
12:00:00.0200 Brand GM before db open
12:00:00.0300 Brand Chevy after db open
12:00:00.0300 Brand Ford after db open
12:00:00.0300 Brand GM after db open
12:00:00.0400 Chevy after enqueue
12:00:00.0400 Ford after enqueue
12:00:00.0400 GM after enqueue
12:00:07.0000 Brand Honda after db open <-- usually around 7 seconds late
12:00:07.0100 Honda after enqueue
```

I can't seem to replicate this problem locally on my SQL Server 2008 instance, but it happens all the time on a SQL Server 2012 instance. The issue seems like a configuration problem. It always happen when I send concurrent requests and whatever the SELECT request is. If I were to do the blocking query in SQL Server Management, it would return in sub 100ms.

Here is my connection string:

```
<add key="SqlConnectionString" value="Data Source=10.0.20.20;Initial Catalog=CarsDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;Connection Timeout=240;" />
```

**Edit:**

I have insert "Min Pool Size=30" in my connection string, it seems like only the first, second or third time the method is hit it runs in +15 seconds, then all other method calls are sub 500ms.

I've also got the SQL Server 2012 running in our test environement with the same meta data in the tables as where the issue is seen, and I can't replicate this problem. It seems like configuration problem somewhere.

Comment: Can you add a debugging line that shows the time after the db connection leaves the `using` statement. `using (var db = new SqlConnection(connectionString)){ /*...*/} sqlLogger.Trace("Brand " + " brand " + " after db close");` then update your question listing the order of statements?

Comment: Is that for real?  You really think making multiple parallel connections to the same table is going to make SQL go faster.  On the other end is a single set of physical disk heads.  You really think multiple connections is a good use of resources?  If five bosses at once tell you what they need does that mean you can work 5 times as fast?

Comment: I actually do, but it is in the proper order, which is why I omitted the extra logging. All using statement are disposed properly after the sql returns. I do not use any db.close() Shouldnt the using statement take care of this?

Comment: @Blam There is more complicated business logic in the actual app, but yah, maybe I could bundle all 20 calls under one.

Comment: Really if 5 bosses tell you what they need at the same time then you can magically work 5 times as fast?

Comment: @Blam maybe I have 5 brains, and I can work in parallel, as opposed to queuing each bosses need. I don't analogies are the way to go here tho. I'll look into bundling multiple calls in 1 call, just not sure how to do so.

Comment: What part of a single physical write head is not clear?  Bundle?   Start with get rid of the Parallel.ForEach.

Comment: Is it possible that the one of the calls before the "Honda" is locking up a table with a heavy query that the "Honda" query depends on? What would happen if you dump out the queries in your log then run them as one large script on your local SQL Server? Does the issue replicate then?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a partitioned table this is insane

```
Parallel.ForEach(brands, brand =>
{
  logger.Trace(brand + " before enqueue");
  foundsCars.Enqueue(FindCar(brand));
  logger.Trace(brand + " after enqueue");
});
```

Multiple connections going after the same table is not faster let alone the overhead of multiple connections.  On the other end you have a single physical read write head.  Do you not get that open and close a connection takes way way longer than a simple read? Really you just line up the table and read from it.  Reader is very very fast.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [MARS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131686.aspx) in your ConnectionString. It should looks like this `Data Source=10.0.20.20;Initial Catalog=CarsDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;Connection Timeout=240;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;`

Comment: MARS will not effect what he is doing. He only has one active reader per connection.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like connection pool exhaustion. Parallel.ForEach is prone to spam insane amounts of threads. Really an unlimited amount for some IO workloads as far as I can tell. Limit the degree of parallelism to a sane value.

Comment: I had a similar type of logic using Tasks combined with WhenAll(), and the issue persisted.

Comment: How many tasks were there? That's even more prone to exhaustion because there is not any throttling going on.

Comment: We are talking 20 to 40 concurrent tasks, from my past experience this isn't that much. You think it is?

Comment: The default pool size is 100, so maybe your workload spikes to >100 rarely. Process your work items at a sane degree of parallelism, for example the count of CPU cores of the db server + 20% or so.

Answer (score 0):

Switching Integrated Security from SSPI to User/Password in the connection string fixed the issue. It seems like one of our environment has issues with Active Directory, while the other doesn't.